# How to create a check to stop entering duplicate value in a text field in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, duplicates

How to prevent user to stop entering duplicate entries.
My controller code is like this:

```
$scope.myData = [];

$scope.obj={title:''};

$scope.IsEdit=false;

$scope.addData = function() {
    if($scope.IsEdit==false){
        $scope.obj.IsCompleted=false;
        $scope.myData.push($scope.obj);
    }
    else{
        $scope.IsEdit=false;
    }
    $scope.obj={};
}
```

Comment: Why do not use dropbox or multi-select? Don't rewheel the wheel

Comment: Before pushing new object into your array myData, check if same object with same title already exists.